# Related Name Issue in my Django Application

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I am trying to change the Django default User Authentication and permissions classes. While trying to do that, I got issues related to the related name and when I added it to my codes it still continued giving me the same issue.

Here is the error log

```
django.core.management.base.SystemCheckError: SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:
ERRORS:
auth.User.groups: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'User.groups' clashes with reverse accessor for 'User.groups'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'User.groups' or 'User.groups'.
auth.User.user_permissions: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'User.user_permissions' clashes with reverse accessor for 'User.user_permissions'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'User.user_permissions' or 'User.user_permissions'.
core.User.groups: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'User.groups' clashes with reverse accessor for 'User.groups'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'User.groups' or 'User.groups'.
core.User.user_permissions: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'User.user_permissions' clashes with reverse accessor for 'User.user_permissions'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'User.user_permissions' or 'User.user_permissions'.

System check identified 4 issues (0 silenced).
```

Here is my models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager, PermissionsMixin
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone


class UserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def _create_user(self, email, password, is_staff, is_superuser, **extra_fields):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')
        now = timezone.now()
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(
            email=email,
            is_staff=is_staff,
            is_active=True,
            is_superuser=is_superuser,
            last_login=now,
            date_joined=now,
            **extra_fields
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email=None, password=None, **extra_fields):
        return self._create_user(email, password, False, False, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        user = self._create_user(email, password, True, True, **extra_fields)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=254, null=True, blank=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    EMAIL_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = UserManager()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/users/%i/" % (self.pk)
    def get_email(self):
        return self.email
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin
from .models import User

# Register your models here.

class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('email', 'password', 'name', 'last_login')}),
        ('Permissions', {'fields': (
            'is_active',
            'is_staff',
            'is_superuser',
            'groups',
            'user_permissions',
        )}),
    )
    add_fieldsets = (
        (
            None,
            {
                'classes': ('wide',),
                'fields': ('email', 'password1', 'password2')
            }
        ),
    )

    list_display = ('email', 'name', 'is_staff', 'last_login')
    list_filter = ('is_staff', 'is_superuser', 'is_active', 'groups')
    search_fields = ('email',)
    ordering = ('email',)
    filter_horizontal = ('groups', 'user_permissions',)

admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

I have also tried adding the AUTH_USER_MODEL='my_app_name.User', still did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I solved the issue.

The problem was that I was trying to make a custom User authentication system where the user could register and login using the email instead of the username and password.

So, I had run the initial `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate` command.

My solution was to delete the migrations folder inside the app as well as the db.sqlite file and then make migrations again as well as migrate, then it worked well.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/#abstract-related-name

```
class Base(models.Model):
    m2m = models.ManyToManyField(
        OtherModel,
        related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_related",
        related_query_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)ss",
    )

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class ChildA(Base):
    pass

class ChildB(Base):
    pass
```